# Show/Hide a Control in a WPF User Control

Tags: c#, wpf

I have 3 buttons in a user control, I would like to **show and hide one button from the WPF application** or from the user control. Its not working for me. I have implemented `INotifyPropertChanged` interface to notify the View. Please check it.

```
<UserControl x:Class="WPFUserControl.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         xmlns:vis="clr-namespace:WPFUserControl"
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <vis:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVis" ></vis:BoolToVisibilityConverter>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Button Content="Button1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
    <Button Content="Button2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Margin="106,0,0,0"/>
    <Button Content="ShowHide" Visibility="{Binding IsShowHideVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}, ConverterParameter=False}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Margin="215,0,0,0"/>

</Grid>
```

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool isShowHideVisible;
    public bool IsShowHideVisible
    {
        get { return isShowHideVisible; }
        set
        {
            if(isShowHideVisible!=value)
            {
                isShowHideVisible = value;
            }
        }
    }
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
       // IsShowHideVisible = false;
    }

    private void OnPropertyChange(string pPropertyName)
    {
        if(PropertyChanged!=null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(pPropertyName));
        }

    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Comment: Include your converter and check `Output` window for any binding exceptions.

Comment: Can you show `BoolToVis` ? Have you tried to see if you're using your converter ?

Comment: you should raise the on property changed like this OnPropertyChanged("IsShowHideVisible")

Comment: OnPropertyChanged("IsShowHideVisible");  add this code after the line :isShowHideVisible = value;

Answer (score 1):

In the setter of your IsShowHideVisible-Property you have to call `OnPropertyChanged("IsShowHideVisible")` right after `isShowHideVisible = value;`.

Your property then looks like:

```
public bool IsShowHideVisible
{
    get { return isShowHideVisible; }
    set
    {
        if(isShowHideVisible!=value)
        {
            isShowHideVisible = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsShowHideVisible");
        }
    }
}
```

If you're using .net 4.5 or higher you can rewrite your `OnPropertyChanged`-Method like:

```
private void OnPropertyChange([CallerMemberName]string pPropertyName = null)
{
    if(PropertyChanged!=null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(pPropertyName));
    }
}
```

Than in your Property you only have to call `OnPropertyChanged();` instead of `OnPropertyChanged("IsShowHideVisible");`

Comment: I added this code, but still not working. can you please look into it.

Comment: In your Binding add `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`. If this is not working please show us the converter you are using to convert bool to visibility

Comment: Hi, problem was inside constructor of UserControl, this required DataContext=this.

Answer (score 0):

After adding this.DataContext=this inside the constructor and OnPropertyChange("IsShowHideVisible") inside the set field , its working.

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool isShowHideVisible;
    public bool IsShowHideVisible
    {
        get { return isShowHideVisible; }
        set
        {
            if(isShowHideVisible!=value)
            {
                isShowHideVisible = value;
                OnPropertyChange("IsShowHideVisible");
            }
        }
    }
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext=this;
    }

    private void OnPropertyChange(string pPropertyName)
    {
        if(PropertyChanged!=null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(pPropertyName));
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```